# How to parse XML through StAX java and generating excel document from it

Tags: java, excel, parsing, xml-parsing, stax

So my overall aim for my programme is for it to be able to parse any XML file, allow the user to specify which elements they want and then to return those elements and values in an excel file. So for example, if I had the xml file:-

```
<metabolite>
  <version>3.5</version>
  <creation_date>2005-11-16 08:48:42 -0700</creation_date>
  <update_date>2013-07-24 11:48:59 -0600</update_date>
  <accession>HMDB00001</accession>
  <secondary_accessions>
    <accession>HMDB04935</accession>
    <accession>HMDB06703</accession>
    <accession>HMDB06704</accession>
  </secondary_accessions>
  <name>1-Methylhistidine</name>
  <description>One-methylhistidine (1-MHis) is derived mainly from the anserine of dietary flesh sources, especially poultry. </description>
  <synonyms>
    <synonym>1 Methylhistidine</synonym>
    <synonym>1-Methyl histidine</synonym>
    <synonym>1-Methyl-Histidine</synonym>
    <synonym>1-Methyl-L-histidine</synonym>
    <synonym>1-MHis</synonym>
    <synonym>1-N-Methyl-L-histidine</synonym>
    <synonym>L-1-Methylhistidine</synonym>
    <synonym>N1-Methyl-L-histidine</synonym>
    <synonym>Pi-methylhistidine</synonym>
  </synonyms>
  <chemical_formula>C7H11N3O2</chemical_formula>
</metabolite>
```

and I wanted to retrieve chemical formulas for all metabolites, it would simply output the values, or say if I wanted to retrieve all Synonyms, it would do that for all metabolite entries. Basically this program needs to be able to deal with complicated XML files that are large. The XML files I'm parsing are huge so I decided to use StAX and have done this so far:-

```
public class xmlRead {

    XMLStreamReader reader;

    public XMLStreamReader XMLRead() throws XMLStreamException{

        try{

            XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

            InputStream file = new FileInputStream("/Users/Kevlar/Dropbox/PhD/Java/XML/HMDB00001.xml");

            reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(file);

            assert(reader.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_DOCUMENT);   

        }   catch (XMLStreamException e){
            System.err.println("XMLStreamException : " + e.getMessage());

        }   catch (FactoryConfigurationError e){
            System.err.println("FactoryConfigurationError : " + e.getMessage());

        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("FileNotFoundException : " + e.getMessage());

        }
        return reader;  
    }

    public void metaboliteInfo(XMLStreamReader reader) throws XMLStreamException{

        while(reader.hasNext()){

        reader.next();

        int event = reader.getEventType();

        switch(event){

        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
            System.out.println("New " + reader.getLocalName());

            mainElements(reader);

        case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
            break;
        }

        }

        reader.close();
    }
    public void mainElements(XMLStreamReader reader) throws XMLStreamException{

            int level = 1;

            do{

                int event = reader.next();

                if(event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){

                    System.out.println("Element :" + reader.getLocalName());
                    level++;

                    if(level == 2){
                        subElements(reader);
                        level--;
                    }
                }

                else if(event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS && !reader.isWhiteSpace()){
                    System.out.println(reader.getText());
                }

                else if(event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT){
                    level--;
                }

            }while(level > 0);

        reader.close();

    }

    private void subElements(XMLStreamReader reader) throws XMLStreamException {

        int level = 1;

        do{

            int event = reader.next();

            if(event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){

                System.out.println("Sub element :" + reader.getLocalName());
                level++;

                if(level == 2){
                    subElements(reader);
                    level--;
                }
            }

            else if(event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS && !reader.isWhiteSpace()){
                System.out.println(reader.getText());
            }

            else if(event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT){
                level--;
            }

        }while(level > 0);

    reader.close();

}

    public void findElement(XMLStreamReader reader, String element) throws XMLStreamException{

        while(reader.hasNext()){

            int event = reader.getEventType();

            if(event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT && reader.getLocalName() == element){
                    System.out.println(reader.getLocalName());
                    mainElements(reader);
                    break;

            } else{
                reader.next();
            }
        }


    }
```

It's able to parse through the document in order and retrieve values from elements and subelements when specified, however it's not the best way of doing it. I was wondering whether anyone had any suggestions or could even go about improving what I've done so it's not as inefficient? Also, does anyone have any idea how I can go from this to then exporting the information into an excel sheet?

Thanks

Comment: For exporting to Excel, have a look at Apache POI.

Comment: thanks! I'll have a look at that now